# Node.js javascript and html script not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

okay so I am trying to make my html/javascript communicate with my nodes.js server.
what I am trying to do is post data to my nodes.js server then echo the result back into my html/javascript.

the communication is working as in node I have console.log  for the postdata and I can see it via the running node console .

problem is I need javascript to wait for the node.js function to complete and then echo me the text produced by node back to the html page.

I just cannot get this to work heres my html/javascript

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html><head><title>Welcome To ....</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function textareaToArray(t){
    return t.value.split(/[\n\r]+/);
}
function showArray(msg){
    for(i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
        // something per item
        var data = {}; //your own data
     $.post("http://192.168.2.109:8111" + "?" + $.param({name: msg[i]}), data);

    }
    // the old code
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = msg.join("&#013;");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> WELCOME TO .... </h1>
<form>
<textarea rows="10" cols="60" name="alpha"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" value="show array" onclick="showArray(textareaToArray(this.form.alpha ))">
</form>
<br>
<textarea id="message" rows="6" cols="60" name="message"></textarea>
</body></html>
```

and here is my node script

```
  var url = require('url')
  var http = require('http')
  var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  var queryData = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});

  if (queryData.name) {
    // user told us their name in the GET request, ex: http://host:8000/?name=Tom
    var basevalue = queryData.name;
    var value = basevalue.split (":");

    console.log(value[0]);
    console.log(value[1]);

    var exec = require('child_process').exec;

    exec ("casperjs test.js " + value[0] + " " + value[1] + '\n',function(err, stdout, stderr) {

        response.end(stdout);

    });

  } else {
    response.end("Contact Admin - Not Working\n");
  }
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8111);
```

can someone please show me and help me fix this thanks

Comment: you need to load jQuery before you use it. and you need a scope condom on your for-loop to close "i"

Comment: sorry I left the jqeury line out i am getting this header error XMLHttpRequest cannot load with javascript any ideas

Answer (score 1):

IT is simple. 
you need to call the alert in callback. so it will be executed when post request completed. 
change your few lines as following

```
$.post("http://192.168.2.109:8111" + "?" + $.param({name: msg[i]}), function(data){

    // data contains your response from server. now you can handle it as you want
});
```

Comment: this is incorrect alert is only there to make sure my script was working edited post . and like I said I want the result from the Node.js result not msg[I]

Comment: wrap the for-loop body in a self-invoked function with an "i" formal parameter and passing "i" as the argument at invocation.

Comment: yes. do console.log or echo and check the response and change your code accordingly.